# C++ Reading a file with multiple types on same line

Tags: c++, file

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Mike 1200
John 350
Jen 1500
Tara 700
Michelle 2000
Kevin 500
Matt 450
Kim 200
```

My code to store the contents:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 15;

int main() {

// declare variables
string names[MAX];
string tempscore;
float scores[MAX];
fstream infile;

infile.open("winners.txt", ios::in);

int cc = 0;

getline(infile, names[cc], ' ');

infile.ignore( 0, ' ');

infile >> tempscore;
infile.ignore( 1, '\n');

scores[cc] = strtof(tempscore.c_str(), NULL);

    cout << "'" << names[cc] << "'" << endl;
    cout << "'" << scores[cc] << "'" << endl;

int i = 1;

while (infile) {

    getline(infile, names[i], ' ');

    infile.ignore( 0, ' ');

    infile >> tempscore;
    infile.ignore( 1, '\n');

    scores[cc] = strtof(tempscore.c_str(), NULL);


    cout << "'" << names[i] << "'" << endl;
    cout << "'" << scores[i] << "'" << endl;
    i++;
}
infile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Most of the names are stored correctly but none of the scores are. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Is this the best way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. `scores[cc] = strtof(tempscore.c_str(), NULL);` should be `scores[i] = strtof(tempscore.c_str(), NULL);` in the `while` loop.

A few side notes:

1. There is no need to handle index `0` separately
2. You should check your array bounds in the `while` loop. Consider using `vector` if possible
3. As [stefaanv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104774/stefaanv) has pointed out in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777659/c-reading-a-file-with-multiple-types-on-same-line/16777984#comment24188040_16777984) below, you are not checking the return value of `getline`. If you want to keep you code as is without making use of `stringstream` consider changing the `while` condition to `while(i < MAX && getline(infile, names[i], ' '))` (and ofc, getting rid of subsequent `getline` call. Please note that it is important that `i < MAX` check is before `getline` otherwise there is a possibility of segmentation fault as `names[i]` is used in `getline`)
4. If you are using `C++11`, consider using [`stof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/) instead of `strtof` as it operates directly on `string` and there is no need to get C-str for it

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay so I read all of the replies and I'm unfamiliar with the stringstream method and re-formatting my file isn't an option for me.
So, I used the method I am most familiar with.

I edited my code and it seems to work, except now I'm getting an extra (blank) name in my `names[]` array and the final score in the file (200) is also being appended twice. Once for "Kim" and another for the blank name.

Any ideas as to why this is so?

Comment: @EliNahon: You don't check whether `getline(infile, names[i], ' ');` actually succeeded.  The last time it fails but you continue.  Reading to tempscore fails to, but you continue with what is already in tempscore.  I'll make an example of how to do this with the stringstream method.

Comment: @EliNahon: Please see the edit. stefaanv has already pointed out the reason for the problem

Answer (score 2):

For linebased file parsing, first read the line and put it in a stringstream, then read out each field directly from that stringstream, without storing it in a string and converting.

```
int main() {
const int MAX = 15;

// declare variables
std::string names[MAX];
float scores[MAX];
std::fstream infile;

infile.open("winners.txt", std::ios::in);

int i = 0;
std::string line;

while (getline(infile, line)) {
    std::stringstream input(line);

    input >> names[i] >> scores[i];
    if (input) {
        std::cout << "'" << names[i] << "'" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'" << scores[i] << "'" << std::endl;
        i++;
        if (i >= MAX) break;  // protect your array or use a vector or deque
    }
}
infile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tested. It works. :) Although you might want to add `std::` to some types in your code, as you already have done with the `std::string line`.

Comment: Thanks, the std:: thing is because I started from the code in the question.  There are more things that I would change...

Comment: You can now remove the `example not compiled or tested` line :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use `getline` twice, do `getline(infile, names[cc], ' ');` and `getline(infile, score[cc], ' ');`

Or format the text file like this:

```
Mike 
1200

John 
350

Jen 
1500
```

etc.

In this case, every third line contains the score, started by 2 and names are the same but started by 1. Count 1, 4, 7, 10, etc. and 2, 5, 8, 11, etc. and you know, which are the names and which are the scores.

EDIT: it's not an answer to the main question, but may be a good implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that file format, you could do the following:

> 1. Read the line
> 2. Get the position of the first space character that you find (since that is your separator)
> 3. Split the string from that position.
> 4. Store the first half into your string array, and then store the output of the function atoi(secondHalf.c_str()) called with the second
>      half as parameter into your score array.

I would also change the score array to int instead of float if you are not using real numbers.

UPDATE:
This is an example code of what I am trying to tell you. I'm using vectors for names and scores here:

```
int i = 0;
for(i=0; i<line.size(); i++)
{
    if(line[i] == ' ') break; //Then we have the position of the space char
}
names.push_back(line.substr(0,i));
scores.push_back(std::string(atoi(line.substr(i))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use C functions to read formatted lines from the file :

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
int score = 0;
char name[20];
fp = fopen("winners.txt", "r");
if(!fp)
 return -1;

while(tell(fp) != EOF) {
 fscanf(fp, "%s %d", name, &score);
 printf("Name : %s, Score : %d", name, score);
}
```

do not forget to `#include <cstdio>`